# NodeJS execSync with custom stdout stream for collecting output and logging to terminal on the fly

Tags: node.js

When you use execSync then you can specify stdio:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

Number five says that you can pass a Stream object:

> 5. object - Share a readable or writable stream that refers to a
>      tty, file, socket, or a pipe with the child process. The stream's
>      underlying file descriptor is duplicated in the child process to the
>      fd that corresponds to the index in the stdio array. Note that the
>      stream must have an underlying descriptor (file streams do not until
>      the 'open' event has occurred).

However, I am unable to pass an object. I've tried:

```
const { PassThrough, Writable } = require('stream');
const pass     = new PassThrough();
```

Which I found here:

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_three_states

But I couldn't pass that as stdio: [..., stdout, ...] for **execSync** options method call.

```
require('child_process').execSync(command, options);
```

Anyone?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Kind of, but I never implemented it. The only way is basically to do it async, wait below, write to a file, then read from it and log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says -

> a readable or writable stream that refers to a tty, file, socket, or a
>   pipe with the child process

So, you cannot use any stream you like. I don't know the underlying reason however. Below is how you can make it work using a fs.createWriteStream. Note the 'open' event - that seems to be important, if not waiting for that event before invoking the childProcess.exec, you'll get an error.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const childProcess = require('child_process')

const stream = new fs.createWriteStream('out')
stream.on('open', function() {
    childProcess.execSync('ls -la', {stdio:['ignore', stream, stream]})
})
```

As an alternative you can also pass a file descriptor to the stdio array entries. What I am personally also missing is the possibility to pass in any kind of streams, especially 'through' streams that would allow to tee the output to multiple sinks. As mentioned I don't know why this is - there might be a good reason for it. Hope someone else can provide more details.

Comment: I suppose it's the only way to merge the stdout and stderr in the same stream ?